# How to repair a php file corrupted by dreamweaver on power fail

Tags: php, file, dreamweaver

I am facing an insane situation here, i was working on a php file my laptop suddenly turned off (power fail) when i started the laptop and open dreamweaver the file was renamed to something.tmp and then the file size is correct but the actual file is empty?

have you geniuses every faced such a situation, just don't tell me to redo it again. i will hang myself.

Comment: Apparently when i duplicated the file and turned it to .txt it shows spaces like a million times.

Comment: While I do sympathize with your situation I kind of feel like this is what a person gets for using Dreamweaver for PHP development in 2014.

Comment: @Alternatex which program do you prefer? i have got used to it for the last 10 years it was the first time i faced this situation and i am redoing the whole thing over again, i just had to update my DW.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-ide-2014-survey-results/). Most people are amazed Dreamweaver is even on the list.

Comment: I am suffering from the same problem, I retrieve the .css file from firefox cache using about:cache but can not find php file